# ActimeMQ One Producer with two queue(NormalJob and Emergenecy Job) with two consumer (separate for both queue)

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have two types of jobs(Emergency job and normal job) to be sent for processing. There is only on instance of Processing Engine and can processed only one job at time. Now the requirement is that first 4 emergency jobs should be sent for processing and then 2 normal jobs.

I have done poc with two queue(N.Q and E.Q) and one producer sending job on it.

```
public void receive() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    try {
        Connection connectionEmergency = factory.createConnection();
        connectionEmergency.start();
        Session sessionEmergency = connectionEmergency.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destinationEmergency = sessionEmergency.createQueue("EMERGENCYQUEUE");
        MessageConsumer consumerEmergency = sessionEmergency.createConsumer(destinationEmergency);

        Connection connectionNormal = factory.createConnection();
        connectionNormal.start();
        Session sessionNormal = connectionNormal.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destinationNormal = sessionNormal.createQueue("NORMALQUEUE");
        MessageConsumer consumerNormal = sessionNormal.createConsumer(destinationNormal);

        int countNormal = 0;
        int countEmergency = 0;
        while (true) {

            while (countEmergency < 4) {
                TextMessage message = (TextMessage) consumerEmergency.receive(1000);
                if (message != null) {
                    sendForDeployment(message.getText(), (countEmergency + 1));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("************Message is null in Emergency**********");
                    break;
                }
                countEmergency++;
            }
            countEmergency = 0;

            while (countNormal < 2) {
                TextMessage message2 = (TextMessage) consumerNormal.receive(1000);
                if (message2 != null) {
                    sendForDeployment(message2.getText(), (countNormal + 1));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("*************Message is null in Normal***********");
                    break;
                }
                countNormal++;
            }
            countNormal = 0;
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Problem with this code is that when both the queues are empty, it is continuously running :( . I want to wait when queues become empty and re-trigger somehow when any of the queue got message. Please help to get some better solution with it.

Comment: for 'event-based' computing, did you ever consider using topics instead of queues ? If you listen on topics you are notified whenever a message arrives. If you are concerned about loosing messages while the subscriber is down, consider durable subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks for reply Axel, Actually I am new to JMS, can you please explain it with some example, as i am not getting how to send message for processing from topic to processing engine.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your use case, but you should try with consumerEmergency.setMessageListener( ... ) and consumerNormal.setMessageListener( ...) methods. Then your processing is asynchronous - callbacks will be invoked instead of you having to poll for the example. Forget about topics for now.

Comment: But I need to send the messages received from both the queue for processing in some pattern like first 4 messages from E.Q then  2 messages from N.Q ..if somewhere suppose E.Q is not having 4 message or empty then instead of doing wait over there, N.Q consumer should start processing. I hope you are getting my point. I don't know how to get this functionality if I go with aync approach. .

Comment: Actually E.Q's message should be given more chances to run as compare to N.Q's messages. So I decided to process 4 message from N.Q and then 2 from E.Q. .